# How to run a simple toggle function on load (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get my sidebar to slide in by toggling the state of my Sidebar (going from open: false to open: true) on component load. I'm doing this is an attempt to get a slide-in effect once the user loads the page.

Unfortunately, the way I'm currently doing this, it appears as though the state is changed and the component re-rendered essentially immediately, preventing the slide-in effect from happening. Here's my code:

```
export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer width={'25%'} open={this.state.open}>
         <AppBar title="Wealth Management" onLeftIconButtonClick={this.handleToggle}/>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do you get this to work? Am I updating on the wrong lifecycle method?

Answer (score 1):

It is called *CSS transition*.

You could have a look at this [medium post](https://medium.com/@joethedave/achieving-ui-animations-with-react-the-right-way-562fa8a91935) or check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: The issue isn't the lack of transition - it's the fact that it occurs before the component is rendered. I'm just trying to figure out the correct lifecycle method to make that happen

Answer (score 0):

We use a sidebar that slide open or closed based on user settings, the trick is to set a negative margin on the base css-class "sidebar" in this case.
Then add/remove the toggle class (on render or button event). That is all that is required to get a smoth animation on load

css-classes:

```
.sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebarToggled {
  width: 65px;
}
```